# Windows XP doesn't find second physical sata HDD but is detected in BIOS and Hiren's

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, bios, sata

On my motherboard there are two SATA ports. First is HDD 80 GB with system. I connected 250 GB HDD to the second. This is detected by BIOS and also under [Hiren's Boot CD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd) but not under Windows XP.

How can I get Windows XP to find the second HDD(250 GB) ?

Comment: since I am new to this site, I would be glad to get some help also in the way of asking and participating here,.

Comment: It would help if you [edit] in and post what your actual question is. Right now you seem to have missed few works

Comment: Is the second hard drive formatted???

Comment: second drive is formated ( I have done it firstly I found it in HirensWinxp, ofcourse in NTFS format and suggested defaults)

Comment: Are both drives connected to the same SATA controller? If they are not, are the drivers for both SATA controllers loaded? (In both cases the firmware (BIOS or EFI) would detect the drives, but once the OS takes over it will not see them until drivers for the SATA controller are loaded).

Comment: Both drives are connected to onboard sata controller,

Answer (score 1):

I am answering this question assuming you can boot from the 80GB disk's system without relying on the Boot CD!

I'd check Disk Management to see if the disk is seen, but not partitioned or formatted in way the system understands.

To get there:

1. Right click 'My Computer'
2. Click 'Manage'
3. Click 'Disk Management'

I think you will be able to see the disk, but you will see no usable partitions in there. You might have to create a partition and format it or format an existing partition.

I might be able to answer the question further if you post a screenshot of what Disk Management shows you.

Your SATA controller is working and seen by the system, so it is almost certainly NOT a driver issue.

Chances are there are some settings in the Boot CD that make the drive appear that are not configured the same way in the Windows XP system on the 80GB hard drive.

Comment: thank you, but I already checked that with Disk Management, and there is seen just hdd80gb with system, even if I click rescan hard drives. I wont screenshot you Disk Management becouse of that.